# How to Load Multiple Gltf with Single Mind file

Tags: javascript, mindar

Hello Guys I am in A Small Confusion That How can u scan Multiple images and load Multiple Gltf With Single Mind file i am providing a code just help me out how did they Load the Gltf with single mind file and if i have to do same process how can i do that

```
<a-scene mindar-image="imageTargetSrc: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hiukim/mind-ar-js@1.2.1/examples/image-tracking/assets/band-example/band.mind; maxTrack: 2" color-space="sRGB" renderer="colorManagement: true, physicallyCorrectLights" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false">
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="bearModel" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hiukim/mind-ar-js@1.2.1/examples/image-tracking/assets/band-example/bear/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
    <a-asset-item id="raccoonModel" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hiukim/mind-ar-js@1.2.1/examples/image-tracking/assets/band-example/raccoon/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>

  <a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled: false"></a-camera>

  <a-entity mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 0">
    <a-gltf-model rotation="0 0 0 " position="0 -0.25 0" scale="0.05 0.05 0.05" src="#raccoonModel" animation-mixer>
  </a-entity>
  <a-entity mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 1">
    <a-gltf-model rotation="0 0 0 " position="0 -0.25 0" scale="0.05 0.05 0.05" src="#bearModel" animation-mixer>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have missed the part where you can upload multiple images to the [image compilation](https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/tools/compile/) tool in mindar. After the compilation (where all the targets get compiled to one single mind file), it specifically shows the [target image numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoL7i.png) (1-indexed). Hence you can use zero-based indexing to specify the targets.

```html
<a-entity mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 0">
   ...
</a-entity>
<a-entity mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 1">
   ...
</a-entity>
```

Hope this clears your doubt.